# Is std::array movable?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, move-semantics

**Is std::array movable?**

In [Bjarne Native 2012 presentation slides](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf) (slide 41) it lists `std::array` as one of the only containers that isn't movable.

A quick look on gcc 4.8 libraries source code seems to confirm that `std::array` is not movable:

std::vector:

```
/* @brief  %Vector move constructor.
   ...       */
  vector(vector&& __x) noexcept
  : _Base(std::move(__x)) { }
```

while in std::array the only method that receives a rvalue reference parameter is the random element access, which avoids a return by copy:

```
get(array<_Tp, _Nm>&& __arr) noexcept
    { /*...*/ return std::move(get<_Int>(__arr)); }
```

**Is move-constructor and move-assignment for `std::array` defaulted created, or is `std::array` unmovable? If it is unmovable, why `std::array` cannot be moved while `std::vector` can?**

Comment: As a point of interest, the presence or absence alone of a move constructor is not enough to establish that a type is or isn't move constructible (if using the expression/concepts-oriented view on the matter, as is most common). Similarly for move assignment.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`std::array` is movable only if its contained objects are movable.

`std::array` is quite different from the other containers because the container object contains the storage, not just pointers into the heap. Moving a `std::vector` only copies some pointers, and the contained objects are none the wiser.

Yes, `std::array` uses the default move constructor and assignment operator. As an aggregate class, it's not allowed to define any constructors.

Comment: And the default move constructor for an array moves each of the elements?

Comment: @SethCarnegie It move-constructs the member array, which moves each of its elements.

Comment: Thanks! So a move operation in an std::array is O(n), since move occurs in reality on its elements, while in a std::vector it would be O(1)? (since in the std::vector case only the pointer needs to be moved)

Comment: If the elements of `std::array` are PODs, Won't it just do one `memcpy`? Will it be still O(n)?

Comment: @balki `memcpy` is still O(n).

Comment: @AlessandroStamatto Though even if O(n) you can still profit from the movement of the individual elements. So in general moving a `std::array<std::string>` should still be better than copying it.

Comment: @ChristianRau, yes, I think that the elements of the `std::array` should cna be moved to be moved. However the implementation of `std::array` doesn't agree with us, because `std::move(arr)[n]` is not an r-value, like `std::move(Carr)[n]` is. I think this is a defect on `std::array`. So we are only left with "manually" forcing the cast on each element `std::move(arr[n])`.