# Moving array of unique_ptr<T> in a recursive data structure

Tags: c++, recursion, move-semantics

Attempting to compile the following code results in the following compile error:

> error C2280:
>   'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const
>   std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to
>   reference a deleted function

My understanding is that the array 'm_children' should be movable since the type pointed to by unique_ptr has a move constructor defined.

Unless this is an error being caused by the recursive nature of the class or some element of move semantics that I have overlooked?

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class OctreeNode{
public:
    OctreeNode(){ };
    OctreeNode(OctreeNode&& other) : m_children(std::move(other.m_children)){};
private:
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<OctreeNode>, 8> m_children;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    OctreeNode T;
    std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiles in clang and gcc.

Comment: What compiler are you using and what compile options?

Comment: You could reduce your example `main` to `struct SomeStruct{}; std::array<std::unique_ptr<SomeStruct>, 1> foo, bar; foo = std::move(bar);`

Comment: @Nathan Oliver msvc, visual studio 2013.

Comment: I don't have VS 2013 but it does compile on VS2015.  Do you have CTP2?

Comment: VC++ (with VS2013) still has a way to go with C++11 support. I couldn't find an open bug on this but I didn't look all that hard either.

Comment: I shall update my version of visual studio and report back but judging by the other answers I guess that is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like in vs2013 that definition of `std::array` in the `<array>` header doesn't include a move constructor or move assignment operator.

Under C++ rules these should be automatically generated (and so unnecessary to manually define), but msvc didn't include implicit generation of those until vs2015.

Answer (score 2):

according to the error message, it doesn't call the move constructor of the unique_ptr. Instead, it calls the copy-constructor of it which is not exist. So, iterate over the unique_ptrs and call move constructor explicitly.

```
    int i = 0;
    for(auto& x : other.m_children)
        m_children[i++] = std::move(x);
```

Btw, normally it should work because std::array is movable if and only if the element that it stores is movable too. In you case, unique_ptr is movable so that it shouldn't be problem. Please refer to below link for more detailed discussion

[Is std::array movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370730/is-stdarray-movable)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe std::array would have compiler-generated move operations if there are copy equivalents present, or am I wrong?

And as a sidenote, to move those unique_ptrs one could use std::move algorithm instead of raw loop:

```
std::move(std::begin(other.m_children), std::end(other.m_children), std::begin(m_children));
```