# Does right value of an array will improve performance?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

For example, I have

```
class A
{
    std::array<Object, 5> m_objects;

    A(std::array<Object, 5> objects)
       : m_objects(std::move(objects)) //does using right value will improve 
                                       // performance in some cases??
    {}
};
```

Does using right value  in constructor will improve performance in some cases??

Comment: Take a universal reference if you wan't to improve performance (in some cases)

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370730

Comment: "right value"? Do you mean "rvalue"?!

Answer (score 1):

You should add another constructor to accept temporary arrays as well.

```
class A
{
    std::array<Object, 5> m_objects;

    A(std::array<Object, 5> objects)
       : m_objects(std::move(objects)) 
    {}
    A(std::array<Object, 5>&& robj): m_objects(std::move(robj))
    {}
};
```

You could have also gone with a `forwarding reference` `T&&`, but I left that out here for clarity. This is more explicit.

Also NOTE that, using move in this case does not always guarantee performance. For `array` move implies, moving the elements held by the `array`. In this case, `Object` class instances.

For this to perform better, you SHOULD provide a `move constructor` to `Object` class, else the move operation here will be nothing but copy of individual `Object` instances.

NOTE: The move constructor of the `Object` should be cheaper than the copy constructor. Otherwise there would be no difference between move and copy performance-wise.