# Perfect forwarding array of objects

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I have a class `Object` with a non-default constructor, and a class `ManyObjects` that contains an array of `Object`s. This array should be initialized by the user, using the parameters of the constructor.

Then there is a class `ManyObjectsWrapper` that inherits from `ManyObjects` and also expects an array to initialize `ManyObjects`.

This is the code I'm currently using.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

#define PRINTFN() std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl

class Object {
  public:
    Object(int number) : number(number) { PRINTFN(); }
    Object(Object &&o) : number(std::move(o.number)) { PRINTFN(); }
    // Object(Object&&) = default;
    void print() { std::cout << "The number is " << number << std::endl; }

  private:
    const int number;
};

template <size_t N>
class ManyObjects {
  public:
    ManyObjects(Object(&&objects)[N]) : objects(std::move(objects)) {}
    void print() {
        for (Object &object : objects)
            object.print();
    }

  private:
    Object objects[N];
};

template <size_t N> 
class ManyObjectsWrapper : public ManyObjects<N> {
  public:
    ManyObjectsWrapper(Object(&&objects)[N])
    : ManyObjects<N>(std::forward<Object[N]>(objects)) {}
};

int main() {
    ManyObjectsWrapper<3> wrapper = {{1, 2, 3}};
    wrapper.print();
}
```

**Output**

```
Object::Object(int)
Object::Object(int)
Object::Object(int)
Object::Object(Object&&)
Object::Object(Object&&)
Object::Object(Object&&)
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
```

It works, and the output seems alright, but I'm not sure if my use of rvalue references and `std::forward` & `std::move` is correct. 
Especially the initialization of `ManyObjects::objects` using `objects(std::move(objects))`.
Could someone comment on this?

**Edit**

Some clarifications: I am using this with a microcontroller platform that does not support the STL. I can port simple compile-time constructs like `std::forward` by manually porting them. However, I cannot use dynamic containers like `std::vector` as they use the heap, which I have to avoid on the constrained hardware I'm using.
I would like to keep dependencies to a minimum, and I'd prefer not to waste time porting large parts of the STL (e.g. `std::array`).

The main goal is to be able to call `ManyObjectsWrapper<3> wrapper = {{1, 2, 3}};` where the argument will always be a list of integer literals.

Comment: Read [this](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html), it contains everything you need to know to work with them.

Comment: @Ron, I don't think I understand what you mean, could you elaborate? Simply replacing `std::move` with `std::forward` doesn't compile.

Comment: Wonder why gcc compiles `ManyObjects(Object(&&objects)[N]) : objects(std::move(objects)) {}` C-arrays are not copyable/movable that way.

Comment: @Jarod42, indeed, clang chokes on that line, but gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) compiles and runs fine. Any idea for a better approach?

Comment: why not *vector<Object>* instead of *Object objects[N];*?

Comment: @wtom Because it's not supported on the microcontroller architecture I'm using (because of the heap usage of vector etc.).

Comment: `std::array<Object, N>` is copyable/moveable (but minear time) contrary to C-arrays.

Comment: @Jarod42 `std::array` is not supported on the microcontroller architecture (AVR) I'm using. Are there alternatives, or could I manually add support for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370730/is-stdarray-movable

Comment: also you can try stack allocator, but if you Object basically can be copied or copy constructed, may be there is no point in move semantics at all?

Answer (score 4):

Perfect forwarding makes sense only for *universal references* as Scott Meyers calls them. With universal references, we don't know whether we will get an rvalue or an lvalue and therefore we can't simply `std::move` the parameter since it may be just an lvalue reference.

In your case, there are no universal references present. Your template argument is just a number - array size. For an rvalue reference to be a universal reference, type deduction has to take place (either by template or by auto) - that is not the case in your example, hence your references are just simple rvalue references.

I've put it very simply, for more (and more accurate) information about universal references see [this Scott Meyers article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: I guess I have some more reading to do, I'm currently working through the [link](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) provided by Passer By, I'll read your article next. Can you recommend an approach for initializing the `ManyObjects::objects` array by using a syntax like `ManyObjectsWrapper<3> wrapper = {{1, 2, 3}};`? The arguments will always be a brace-enclosed list of int literals.

Comment: For the braced initialization you describe, you could use initializer lists. E.g., you can have a constructor which takes a parameter of type `std::initializer_list<Object>` and then copy contents of the list to your array. Also, consider using `std::array<int>` if you are trying to use modern C++.

Comment: Initializer lists are not supported on the microcontroller platform I'm using. There are implementations available from third parties, but I'd like to keep dependencies to a minimum if at all possible. Are there alternatives?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry. By the way, since in your example, you have just integers, and static arrays, there can't be any moves anywhere, since the integers need to be copied, and the arrays can be pointed to, but in the end, they need to be copied as well. Moves can occur when the types you use have move ctors and/or operators, and when these operators can move things (usually dynamically allocated memory or other resources etc.).

Comment: I think I'm going to forget about move constructors for now then. At the moment, I can avoid dynamically allocated resources. However, initializing the array (even using a copy ctor) remains a problem. Thank you for your help, that article will definitely come in handy when I improve my C++ knowledge.