# Generalized container usage without copy. Perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following container:

```
constexpr auto id = [](const auto v) {return v;};
template <typename Op, typename Preop=decltype(id)>
class Cont{
public:
    constexpr Cont(const Op & op_,const Preop & preop_=id):op(op_),preop(preop_){}
    constexpr Cont(const Cont & cont_):op(cont_.op),preop(cont_.preop){}
    const Op op ;
    const Preop preop ;
    template <typename Op2, typename Preop2>
    constexpr auto operator()(const Cont<Op2,Preop2> & mfop) const{
        return Cont<const Cont<Op,Preop>,const Cont<Op2,Preop2>>
               (Cont(op,preop),mfop);}
    constexpr auto operator()(const auto & v) const{return op*(preop*v);}
};
```

That I use to make arrays and functors compatible such that, with some proper definitions of `operator*`, the following `main()` is valid:

```
int main(){
    const std::array<double,4> v{};
    const Cont A(Oper<4,1>(1.));
    const Cont B(std::array<std::array<double,4>,4>{std::array<double,4>{}});
    constexpr auto res = B*B*A*A*B*A*B*v;
    return 0;
}
```

The code needs to work at compile time if required. I would like to avoid the multiple copies performed in `Cont`, but I cannot find a way to make it work. Is there maybe a way using perfect forwarding or move semantics?

Comment: You can use forwarding references for template arguments and use `std::forward` to forward them.

Comment: How does this compile exactly? None of these things are multipliable.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal but complete and working example? I don't understand how is defined an `operator*()` involving `[](const auto v) {return v;};`

Comment: Apart of the main question: perfect forwarding will not help if you use only `std::array`s of simple types. Moving and copying for such array is same operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370753/5945883