# C++ Move constructor for object with std::vector and std::array members

Tags: c++, constructor, move, move-constructor

I'm currently implementing a `Vector` class that is supposed to handle the math.
This class has two members `std::vector<double> vector_` and `std::array<std::size_t, 2> size_`.

Now I want to write a move constructor `Vector(Vector&& other);`. I've tried multiple ways, including `Vector(Vector&& other) = default;`, but none seems to do the job correctly. I always end up with both objects having the same `size_` array, instead of the `other` having `{0, 0}`.

Aren't the default move constructor or `std::move(...)` supposed to move the contents and set the `other`'s content to their default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] and set the other's content to their default values?

No. When not stated otherwise a moved from object is in a valid, but unspecified state. Setting all elements to some default would be rather wasteful.

Further, a `std::array` does contain the elements. Its not just a pointer to some dynamically allocated elements that could cheaply be moved. The elements are right within the array. Hence you can only move the individual elements, the array as a whole can only be copied. A `std::array` is moveable when its elements are moveable, otherwise moving it will merely make a copy. For details I refer you to [Is std::array movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370730/is-stdarray-movable).

TL;DR

`Vector(Vector&& other) = default;` is fine. You just expected it do something it does not do. Neither does moving set the moved from elements to some default, nor does moving the `std::array<size_t,2>` actually move the elements, rather it copies them.

Comment: Note, as Howard Hinnant pointed out, the (generally) valid-but-unspecified state of moved standard C++ library objects is not required for your own user-defined types.  Your UDTs can provide whatever post-op guarantees you want, even if "rather wasteful".  (For my own, I use valid-but-unspecified (suitable to be assigned-to, or to be destructed) because there's less to remember.)

Comment: Thanks for your replies! That input helped me a lot to understand the mechanics and to find a solution!

Comment: For usability reasons, the minimum post conditions for move that are usually expected are that the moved from instance should be destructible and assignable.